# Can I stream video from iPhone to VLC?

Tags: iphone, video, vlc

Is there a solution/app available that will allow me to take video **from iPhone/iPad camera** and live-stream it to a VLC player running somewhere else in my WiFi network?

Searching around for iPhone RTP/RTSP encoders isn't coming up with much.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [Airplay](http://www.apple.com/nl/iphone/features/airplay.html) functionality for iPhone ( though I'm not sure if it is available on all iPhone devices, but it is on the 4S ).
Then try and find an [Airplay plugin](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=85338) for VLC.

It's already possible for [Windows Media Player](http://www.redmondpie.com/stream-videos-from-iphone-ipad-ipod-touch-to-windows-media-center-via-airplay/) so VLC can probably do it too ( and be better at it, because you know, it's VLC ).

I haven't tested it myself, but it's probably worth trying out.